# How does Minimize(Hide) Just a Specific Activity , Not Whole Application

Tags: android, android-activity, task, minimized

I am developing an application that user can minimize (hide) resumed activity (but not all the application) by pushing to a button and previous one will be showed. Then, in any activity, by pushing another button, user can see the minimized (hidden) activity again with it's state.

I'm trying two way of solving this problem.

**1 - When activity will be minimized(hide), all it's view's state and attributes will be stored to database after then the activity will be finished.**

**2 - Hold all activities in a separate task(singleInstance) and when it will be minimized, just call movetTaskToBack function.**

How should i do or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Just set the visible state of the containing layout to `View.GONE` (with `setVisibility()`. This will hide all the `View`s on that `Activity`.